# Анимация Activity

Tags: android

Хочу реализовать анимацию астивити как в телеграм(активность выезжает слева и так же смахиванием закрывается). Нашёл на гитхабе [это](https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations). Вопрос. Можно ли реализовать такое встроенными фишками андроид библиотек и как это правильнее сделать

Answer (score 1):

В телеграме, я вам скажу, очень своеобразная архитектура проекта. Там все базируется на одной активити, а все экраны - это View.
В общем возможно это в чем то и правильный подход, но лично мое мнение - так писать не надо. Если интересно, то можете посмотреть что и как там устроено https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram
Есть даже библиотека, которая позволяет такое сотворить(только вот не помню название).

**Отвечая на ваш вопрос**, прям как в телеграмме не получится. Можно добиться анимации, но вот сделать так, чтобы экран двигался за пальцем, словно его пользователь тащит - нет, так нельзя добиться нормальными средствами.

Я, кстати, пытался сделать подобную штуку, основываясь на ViewPager, поменяв анимацию смены страницы, но там появились другие проблемы, связанные с lifecycle. Их тоже пришлось решать костылями.
Собственно вот вам репа с моим проектом https://bitbucket.org/rovkinmax/telegram код там сделан больше для экспериментов, не надо считать, что все что там используется - это круто.
[Тут](https://bitbucket.org/rovkinmax/telegram/src/aa871ccc3512129a2c9ae6a807ea7feee8009d1e/app/src/main/java/android/support/v4/view/StackedViewPager.java?at=develop&fileviewer=file-view-default) можете увидеть ViewPager, а [тут](https://bitbucket.org/rovkinmax/telegram/src/aa871ccc3512129a2c9ae6a807ea7feee8009d1e/app/src/main/java/pro/useit/telegram/activity/BaseActivity.java?at=develop&fileviewer=file-view-default) как он используется, и как там решены некоторые проблемы с lifecycle активити и фрагментов.

Comment: Почему не стоит делать все на одной активити? А то я стараюсь во всех проектах делать так: одна активити, в ней контейнер для фрагментов и туда их гружу.

Comment: так можно делать, но только очень аккуратно. Слишком много логики ляжет в одно место просто. я говорил, что делать не надо основывая все на View вместо фрагментов.